# Monitoring HTTPS traffic using tcpflow

Tags: networking, monitoring, http-logging

I would like to use tcpflow to monitor **https** requests. I have read tutorials on how to monitor http traffic but when I connect to a host using https the output is garbled. I am using tcpflow in the following manner:

```
sudo tcpflow -s -c -i eth0 src or dst host api.linkedin.com
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a copy of the key you can use [`ssldump`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssldump) which uses a syntax almost identical to [`tcpdump`](http://www.tcpdump.org/).

It won't be quite as pretty as [`tcpflow`](http://www.circlemud.org/jelson/software/tcpflow/), but you can get at the encrypted content.

Comment: ssldump link is outdated

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the point of HTTPS. You cannot read (much) meaningful information from a HTTPS stream, as the TCP layer encapsulating it is encrypted. Ultimately that means that the data will look like garbage to anyone trying to intercept it (including you).

Comment: If I am not mistake I would have to set-up a http proxy, any recommendations?

Comment: This is such an old question! You will need to do a 'MITM attack'. As long as the browser/client trusts the ssl certificate put up by the proxy in the middle. On windows, I recall using some web request sniffer tool that can decrypt ssl traffic, which I used for debugging purposes while developing. Can't recall the name though. Companies monitor ssl traffic these days using this approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `sslstrip`.

More info [here](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/index.html)